# Make image div's with overlays fully responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have completed quite a few responsive sites in the past but am struggling with this senario.

I want to generate this effect:
http://playwp.equiet.sk/

I have created a jsfiddle of what I have done, for one of the image divs. I have stripped out the responsive aspects I added as I could not get it to function properly with the overlay and was hoping someone could help me figure this out.

Here is my jsfiddle I want to turn responsive:
http://jsfiddle.net/mattmagi/ZS7ZA/1/

```
<div class="one">
  <img src="http://tst.eclipsecreative.ca/3clips3/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/team.jpg"/>
    <div class="two">
      <img src="http://tst.eclipsecreative.ca/3clips3/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/team-hover.jpg"/>
      <div class="info">
        <p class="name">Sally Salamander</p>
        <p class="position">Account Manager</p>
      </div>
      <div class="social">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://www.tompeters.com/_/i/twitter-icon.png" /></a> <a href="#"><img src="http://www.tompeters.com/_/i/twitter-icon.png" /></a> <a href="#"><img src="http://www.tompeters.com/_/i/twitter-icon.png" /></a>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>


.one {
    position: relative;
    background-color: transparent;
}
.two {
    position: relative;
    top: -364px;
    left: 0px;
}
.info {
position: relative;
top: -365px;
padding-top: 30px;
padding-left: 30px;
background-color: transparent;
}
.social {
position: relative;
top: -365px;
padding-top: 15px;
padding-left: 30px;
background-color: transparent;
}
.name {font-size: 24px;}
.position {font-size: 16px;}
```

EDIT: Ok here is another example of what I mean (ignore the hover glitch):
http://jsfiddle.net/mattmagi/3d5Jr/

The blocks will float to the left, so as your browser gets larger more blocks will show, but when its inbetween sizes I want it to automatically fill the browser so there is never any white-space to the right of the images, so have it scale to fit.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you say responsive, but there are a lot of ways to do this. What are you trying to do? What elements do you want to show or hide, smaller or bigger?

Comment: Do you want the image to scale as the screen does?

Comment: Yes im actually implementing this into that theme I sent a link to above. 

I want it to always fill the screen, but each element have a min width of 540px. So if your screen width is 1440px for instance it would display only two wide, but the div's/images would increase in size scaling to fill the browser window. 

I have managed to get them to be responsive but not to actually scale. Ill quickly whip up a html page for an example.
Sorry its been a long day.

Comment: Ok here is an example of what I mean:
http://jsfiddle.net/mattmagi/3d5Jr/

They will float to the left, so as your browser gets larger more blocks will show, but when its inbetween sizes I want it to automatically fill the browser so there is never any white-space to the right of the images, so have it scale to fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) and percentage widths ..

That way you can define in the media queries how many columns you want by specifying the width of the child elements (*in percentages that add up perfectly to 100%*), and by making the images be `width:100%` inside those elements you make them auto scale..

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/Yz7mf/1/
(*fullscreen at http://fiddle.jshell.net/gaby/Yz7mf/1/show/light/*)

So for a structure of

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/150/city/1" /></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/150/city/2" /></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/150/city/3" /></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/150/city/4" /></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/150/city/5" /></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/150/city/6" /></div>
</div>
```

You can use a Css of

```
#container{
    overflow:auto;
}
#container > div{
    float:left;
}
#container > div > img{
    width:100%;
    display:block;
}

@media screen and (max-width:400px){
  #container > div{
    width:50%;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width:401px) and (max-width:600px){
  #container > div{
    width:25%;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width:601px){
  #container > div{
    width:20%;
  }
}
```

This means that when the browser has width up to 400px use 2 columns, for width between 401px and 600px use 4 columns and for widths larger than 600px use 5 columns.

Comment: Yes thanks but this is not addressing my problem with the hidden div/overlay, I can get the images to do this no problem but it does not function right when I have the overlay as is in my jsfiddle examples in my question. Let me know if you can introduce the overlays into your example and I'm sold.

Comment: @matt, if you make the `.item` in my example to be `position:relative` that you can add another div inside it that is `position:absolute` with top/left/right/bottom being 0, so that it fills its container, and inside it you can put the caption..
see ***http://fiddle.jshell.net/gaby/Yz7mf/5/show/*** and ***http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/Yz7mf/5/*** (*i have used some transitions to showcase some of the effects, but i have only included the standard syntax.. you might want to add vendor specific prefixes to make it work across the browsers..*)

Comment: Thanks a bunch, but my problem is I want the overlay to be another image, or go from grayscale to color...would that still work even having another image in the 2nd div?

Comment: EDIT: Think I got it here: http://jsfiddle.net/mattmagi/Yz7mf/7/ (its only on the 1st image)

Answer (score 0):

I've found this example of what you mean:

http://dabblet.com/gist/2778608

This should help. I'm not sure how to integrate the hover over with this though. Let me know if you figure that out.

Also, try using a responsive framework to save loads of time:

http://foundation.zurb.com

Comment: I do use Zurb my only issue is the overlay, I can get simple images to do this no problem also your example does not have images filling the screen as a grid (side by side). Thanks though.